# Reformulation of $[q^H F_1q\ \dots\ q^H F_n q]^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I have the matrix

$J = \begin{bmatrix}q^H F_1 q  \\ \vdots \\ q^H F_n q\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^n$,

where $q\in\mathbb{C}^{14}$, $E\in\mathbb{C}^{14\times 14}$ and $n$ is a large number. Obviously, the columns of $J$ each contain $q$. I would like to have $J$ reformulated so that $q$ is not repeated. With some help i have gotten so far as this, using the vectorization technique:

$J = \begin{bmatrix}q^H F_1 q  \\ \vdots \\ q^H F_n q\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \text{vec}(F_1)^T \\ \vdots \\ \text{vec}(F_n)^T\end{bmatrix}\text{vec}(qq^H)=A\tilde{q}$.

However, using MATLAB i tested the results. The conclusion is that the outcmoe is not perfect and requires another $\text{conj}(A\tilde{q})$ to be equal. I do not fully understand the derivation and if i am not mistaken, the derivation is (slightly) incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's apply the Kronecker-vec rule to a single (unscripted) term
$$\eqalign{
q^HFq &= {\rm vec}(q^HFq) \\
 &= (q^T\otimes q^H){\rm vec}(F) \\
 &= (q\otimes q^*)^T{\rm vec}(F) \\
}$$
This expression is a **scalar** and therefore unchanged by transposition.
$$\eqalign{
q^HFq &= {\rm vec}(q^HFq)^T \\
 &= {\rm vec}(F)^T(q\otimes q^*) \\
 &= {\rm vec}(F)^T{\rm vec}(q^*q^T) \\
}$$
Now apply this result to the fully subscripted expression
$$\eqalign{
J = \begin{bmatrix}q^H F_1 q  \\ \vdots \\ q^H F_n q\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \text{vec}(F_1)^T \\ \vdots \\ \text{vec}(F_n)^T\end{bmatrix}\text{vec}(q^*q^T)
\\
\\
}$$
Further, if $F$ is hermitian then the scalar expression is also **real** and therefore unchanged by conjugation. So we can write it as
$$\eqalign{
q^HFq &= {\rm vec}(q^HFq)^H \\
 &= {\rm vec}(F)^H(q^*\otimes q) \\
 &= {\rm vec}(F)^H{\rm vec}(qq^H) \\
}$$
Leading to
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix} \text{vec}(F_1)^H \\ \vdots \\ \text{vec}(F_n)^H\end{bmatrix}\text{vec}(qq^H)
$$

Comment: Thank you again sir, really helps a lot.